# Aplicacion creada con tkinter y cx_freeze se abre y se cierra enseguida

Tags: python, tkinter

tengo una aplicación creada con tkinter, python3.6 y empaquetada con cx_freeze con el siguiente archivo setup.py:

```
import os
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\Users\\Alfredo\\Anaconda3\\tcl\\tcl8.6"
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\Users\\Alfredo\\Anaconda3\\tcl\\tk8.6"

buildOptions = dict(
    packages = ['events', 'numpy', 'pandas', 'datetime','matplotlib'],
    excludes = [],
    include_files=['tcl86t.lib', 'tk86t.lib', 'images', 'Usuarios.xlsx']   
)

import sys
base = 'Win32GUI' if sys.platform=='win32' else None

executables = [
    Executable('main.py', base=base, icon = "images/icon.ico")
]

setup(name='editor',
      version = '1.0',
      description = '',
      options = dict(build_exe = buildOptions),
      executables = executables)
```

Bien pues el problema es que me genera el .exe sin errores aparentes pero cuando lo ejecuto se abre la ventana y se cierra al instante. No puedo ver ningún mensaje de error. Alguna solución?? Como puedo lanzarlo desde la consola para ver los errores que me devuelve?

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Para ver los errores que te muestra al ejecutar tu .exe hazlo mediante la consola. 
Si tu archivo se llama editor.exe, abre la consola de windows (cmd) en el directiorio donde esté tu ejecutable y ejecuta:
editor.exe

Ahí te saldrán en consola los errores que aparezcan.

Un saludo.